# Symfony2 Twig: embedding a template - Where to put JS

Tags: symfony, twig

On some of my pages I want to embed a toolbar with some generic functionality like sharing, reporting and bookmarking. Currently I do it like this

```
{# page-detail.html.twig #}
{% extends 'layout.responsive.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "toolbar/index.html.twig" with {'foo':'bar'} %}
    {# further content... #}
{% endblock %}
```

As the features of the toolbar require some information about the context it's embedded in, I pass this information in the with-clause. So far so good.

Now, all the buttons are invoking some JavaScript on clicking. Modal windows are popping up, dialogs are displayed, etc. I would like to put the related JS inside the toolbar template but here is the problem:

All my JS-libraries are loaded at the bottom of the page before the closing body-tag. Means, in my toolbar template I have no access to them.

So I thought of the following solutions which I am not really happy with:

- move the inclusion of the JS-libraries to the top (loading js slows down page display, also JS would be scattered)
- put the respective JS in the javascripts-block in "page-detail.html.twig" (toolbar code is separated from the template code and mixed with the JS-Code needed there)
- use the "embed"-Tag and define a JS-Block in the toolbar-Template (won't help as I can access the blocks in the embedding parent template only within the "embed"-Tag)
- use the "use"-Tag instead. Well that sounds best so far, however, Code would look like this (assuming toolbar-template defines the blocks "toolbar_content" and "toolbar_js"):

Code:

```
{# page-detail.html.twig #}
{% extends 'layout.responsive.html.twig' %}
{% use "toolbar/index.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {% block toolbar_content %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
    {# further content... #}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% block toolbar_js %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
    ... local JS
{% endblock %}
```

Also in this solution I cannot pass the environment variables anymore using the "with"-clause as it is now used for resolving name-conflicts of the blocks.

I feel like I am missing something. How is it done right? It seems like such a common task.

### Additional information

I think not essential for the question but for more clarity, here is how my layout template looks like (not complete just the relevant blocks).

```
{# layout.responsive.html.twig #}
{% block stylesheets %}
     {# bootstrap.css, custom.css, ... #}    
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
     {# jquery, bootstrap, ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

And my toolbar:

```
{# toolbar/index.html.twig #}
<div class="toolbar btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report">Report</button>
    </div>
    <!-- more buttons -->
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you also showed some code from layout.responsive.html.twig (do you define any javascript blocks there?) and toolbar/index.html.twig (how do you use js there?)

Comment: The question is a bit confusing.  I would suggest placing your toolbar javascript code in it's own file (as opposed to in the toolbar template) and then just include it in the javascript block.  I'll admit that the 'use' statement is interesting.  Let us know if you get it to work as desired.